# What do I need if I need a server for my app

Tags: android, webserver

I've never hosted any website on server. I've mostly worked with localhost hence I am not sure what to expect here.

I am trying to work with an android app. Now, this app is not going to be just work on a device without interacting with the outer world. i.e. there will be feature where you can add contacts from your phonebook and then do stuff with them. Basically, if I were to take example, let's say you want to build a simple messaging app.

Now, surely I need to have a server for this (to store the user information, and his activities). Also, I need to write some script on the backend(server) wherein if some user sends a message to another one, then server takes that message and passes on to the intended recepient etc.

Now how exactly do I go about developing something of this sort? Shall I get some server, and what exactly does 'getting a server' entail.

Do I also need a domain name, like you do if you are hosting your website? Shall I first get a server and then start with the development, because I am not sure how to develop/test such app using localhost.

Any reference to any links/resources will be extremely helpful.

Comment: All you need is a server (Space to host your DB and stuff) and a server name (Which translates to a URL)

Comment: There are whole books on this subject. As such, this question is much too broad for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CommonsWare What book should I be aiming for? Anything would be really helpful.

Comment: I worked in the past with CloudBees http://www.cloudbees.com/ they have a good free package to get you started - assuming you plan to develop your server-side application in Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, one thing: You do not need a domain. You can simply address your server via it's IP. However, this is not a good idea. Whenever your IP changes, all the devices would have to update the IP, or they cannot connect anymore.

You can take a look at the ***RESTful*** API for example, which works with HTTP requests. But there are many possible solutions. Basically, what you need is a Server, and (what beginners always forget) a server process which is running on your server and manages the incoming requests.

There is not much more to say at the moment, as for the most part, it is on you to make the first steps. If you have specific problems with programming your server client or your application, we can definitely help you out!

ZerO